# Allow direct access for specific php file

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Rule bellow should block any direct access to all `*.php` files:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.+?\ [^?]+\.php[?\ ]
RewriteRule \.php$ - [F]
```

Is there a way to exclude 1 or 2 php files to be ignored by this global rule?

example:

all `*.php` files (ignored if accessed directly)

`cronjob.php, specialpage.php` (should be ignored by the rule above and direct access should be allowed.)

can you please show example of (1) or (2 or more) files excluded.

PS: if such rule to exclude those files exists, what flag needs to be applied? `[L]` or `[R,L]` or ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negation in `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.+?\ [^?]+\.php[?\ ] [NC]
RewriteRule !(^|/)(cronjob|specialpage)\.php$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: do i still need to include `RewriteRule \.php$ - [F]` behind your negation rule?

Comment: and for single page it would be: `RewriteRule !^cronjob\.php$` - [F,NC] ?

Comment: Yes that's right for 2nd question and no `RewriteRule \.php$ - [F]` shouldn't be used (it should be replaced with `RewriteRule !^(cronjob|specialpage)\.php$ - [F,NC]`)

Comment: it works perfect for almost all files, but for some reason it doesn't work for few files inside /include directory. does it need another negation rule for files in folder (and not in the root) or can this be specified and how in the (cronjob|specialpage)?

Comment: ok check updated rule. It will avoid these files in any folder now.

Comment: seems to work on one some pages and on some it is not. i think i know why, some of the includes loads the files in a iframe (there is no other way). So, so far it works for the root files, directory files. What would you suggest for the iframe loaded php files within the page? maybe adding full url exclusion rule for those?

Comment: `iframe` also sends a `GET` request. You need to check access.log and provide me exact URL for which exclusion isn't working.

Comment: page.php calls iframe with path to include file includepage.php and this one calls another include page subincludepage.php (which contains HTML header and body).